# Electrum and public note

Tags: transactions, electrum

Is it possible to attach a public note to transaction using Electrum client, if yes so how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

Public notes are [a feature of blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/wallet/website-faq) and only exist in the blockchain.info database (and not in the Bitcoin blockchain).

The only way to add a public note to a transaction on blockchain.info seems to be by using their wallet.

Comment: @zied.hosni If that answered your question you should click the ✔-icon next to the vote buttons.